# My Python Counter code is inconsistent, can someone fix it?

Tags: python

**I'm a Beginner;** I'm trying to make a program in python 3.5 that flips a coin 100 times, then counts the amount of heads and tails from those 100 flips and displays it at the bottom. I got the 100 flips to work, and I also tried to make a counter to count the amount of h/t that landed, but it's inconsistent and wonky, and the counters doesn't count the correct amount. I would love it if some one could help me.

```
import random

hcounter = 0
tcounter = 0

while True:
    
    flip = ['heads','tails']

    decision = input("Flip a coin 100 times? (y/n): ")

    if decision == 'y':
#for some reason, the range doubles the number; I dont know why, so since I want 100 flips, I put 50 for the range.
        for x in range(0, 50):
            for y in flip:
                print(random.choice(flip))
        
                if random.choice(flip) == flip[0]:
                    hcounter += 1
                elif random.choice(flip) == flip[1]:
                    tcounter += 1
        
        print("--------------------------------")
        print("Heads: ",hcounter,"\nTails: ",tcounter)
        
    elif decision == 'n':
        print("\nOk")
        break
```

yeah

Comment: Welcome to SO! Every time you call `random.choice(flip)` you do a new flip. Seems like you want to only do one flip in the inner loop and save it in a variable, then increment counters according to that single flip. As it stands, you have as many as three flips in the inner loop and might increment counters over 100. Voting to close as a basic misunderstanding.

Comment: Note that a good SO question is about **one specific problem**, with only the shortest possible code that lets someone reproduce that problem and test their answers; and asked only after it's been verified that that problem hasn't already been asked about & answered in the knowledge base already.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really good start to coding! A few things to fix, let's go through 'em.

```
                if random.choice(flip) == flip[0]:
                    hcounter += 1
                elif random.choice(flip) == flip[1]:
                    tcounter += 1
```

This isn't correct. If it isn't a head, it is a tail, but you call random.choice(flip) again, asking Python if it is now a tail. If it goes tails then heads, we don't add anything.

```
        for x in range(0, 50):
            for y in flip:
```

The first line will make the program run 50 times. But then in each of those 50 loops, the `for y` will make it run 2 times, once with y as `heads` and once for y as `tails`. We don't need this at all.

Apart from that, good job!

```
import random

hcounter = 0
tcounter = 0

while True:
    
    flip = ['heads','tails']

    decision = input("Flip a coin 100 times? (y/n): ")

    if decision == 'y':
        for x in range(0, 50):
    
            if random.choice(flip) == flip[0]:
                print("Heads!")
                hcounter += 1
            else:
                print("Heads!")
                tcounter += 1
        
        print("--------------------------------")
        print("Heads: ",hcounter,"\nTails: ",tcounter)
        
    elif decision == 'n':
        print("\nOk")
        break
```

Comment: thank you so much for the useful feedback! I fixed it and now it works! I am very grateful

Answer (score 1):

The doubling comes from this:

```
for x in range(0, 50):  # 50 loops
        for y in flip:  # each with two more operations
```

An easier way to do this would be something like

```
flip = ['heads', 'tails']
results = [ random.choice(flip) for i in range(100)]
head_counter = results.count(flip[0])
tail_counter = results.count(flip[1])
```

If you want to practice incremental counting:

```
flip = ['heads', 'tails']
results = []
heads, tails = 0, 0
for _ in range(100):
    results.append(random.choice(flip))
    if results[-1] == flip[0]:
       heads += 1
    else:
       tails += 1
enter code here
```

Comment: thanks for showing me how to start practicing incremental counting! I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that without a for-loop:

```
k = 100 # times 
hcounter = sum(random.choices([0,1],k=k)) # or tails if you want :)
print("Heads: ", hcounter,"\nTails: ", k - hcounter )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is great... except for one part. There is a unnecessary line of code in there. You mentioned doubling correct? Well that's were it comes from. I suggest take of the line of code:
`for y in flip:`
You see what this is doing is incrementing through you heads and tails list and size the len of that list is two it doubles. If it was three it would triple. So if you take it off it should only do it once. You code would look like this. Tell me if it works:

```
import random

hcounter = 0
tcounter = 0

while True:
    
    flip = ['heads','tails']

    decision = input("Flip a coin 100 times? (y/n): ")

    if decision == 'y':
#for some reason, the range doubles the number; I dont know why, so since I want 100 flips, I put 50 for the range.
        for x in range(0, 50):
            print(random.choice(flip))
    
            if random.choice(flip) == flip[0]:
                hcounter += 1
            elif random.choice(flip) == flip[1]:
                tcounter += 1
    
        print("--------------------------------")
        print("Heads: ",hcounter,"\nTails: ",tcounter)
        
    elif decision == 'n':
        print("\nOk")
        break
```